# Importing a Windows Image to Google Cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Per the following support article: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image ... it is possible to import RAW Linux images for use in Google Cloud VM's.  However, it makes no mention of Windows instances.  Is this also an option using the same RAW compressed import format?

Answer (score 1):

To the extent that the RAW Windows disk image is GCE compatible (e.g., has all of the required device drivers), it should work from a technical perspective.  The same would be true for any x86 OS, such as FreeBSD, etc.

This ignores any potential licensing issues that you may need to stay in compliance with, however.   If you use a GCE Windows Service Instance, the billing is included in the per-hourly rate charged for the VM.  If you create your own image, it will be up to you to stay in compliance.  Your company might have some bulk volume licensing agreement with Microsoft which covers VM's, but there are often very specific terms you have to follow to stay within compliance of that agreement.